# Autolayout - different space from objects on different screens

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to create a layout for screen and I face a problem - on different screen sizes space between two textviews is different.

[image]

I dont understand why it happens - I explicitly tell IB to make vertical spacing between two views.

My constraints look like this

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong ? Any advices ?

Comment: First of all, get rid of that "magic numbers". Use standard values instead. -4 and -5 doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, the size between the two text views didn't change.

The reason it looks as if there would be more space between is because more texts fits in one line, thus the total height of the text is less on wider devices.

You can see this yourself by changing the background color of the text views.

---

If you're dead certain on needing to have the exact same space between the two text views, regardless of what's in them (take into consideration that the text might be completely different in other languages), you have 2 options:

1. Calculate the height of the text programatically and set a height constraint. The are various methods which allow you to do this (`sizeWithAttributes`, `boundingRectWithSize:`), however it's been long since I used them, they might be deprecated.
2. A niche solution would be to change your whole view to a **table view**. You can make table view cells automatically grow based on content (as of iOS 8).

I prefer the 2nd solution.

Comment: You right. How can I change constrains to make it look similar everywhere ?

Comment: Even though I would recommend not spending too much time with this and just simply leaving it as is, I've posted two possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to take care of this in code. What I believe is happening is your text views are taking up a certain amount of space even if there isn't enough text to fill that space. Then, spacing is applied from the bottom of this.

Add a background colour to your text views and this should show if this is happening or not.

If this is the case, you will need to update the text view size based on the provided text.

**EDIT**

Off the top of my head. Could you not just use one textview and use attributed text to add paragraphs with spacing between them?